# Google Authentication can't find .p12 file

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

I am trying to make an app that will edit my google spreadsheet.

But i am having some problems with the authentication part.
Right now my code for the authentication looks like this.

```
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    File p12 = new File("./Key.p12");

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    String [] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"};
    final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);


    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXgserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                .build();
```

But this when i try to run this the app crashes on the Google credentials builder.This is the error i recieve:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /./Key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:670)
at com.example.XXXX.UpdateSpreadsheet.authenticate(UpdateSpreadsheet.java:57)
at com.example.XXXX.UpdateSpreadsheet.doInBackground(UpdateSpreadsheet.java:124)
at com.example.XXXX.UpdateSpreadsheet.doInBackground(UpdateSpreadsheet.java:39)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
    ... 11 more
```

I have tried different paths for the path of the p12 file but none of them work. I tried "./Key.p12", "/Key.p12", "Key.p12" and also the full path to the file but that also didn't work.

It says that it is not able to open it but i have placed it in the project directory like "Projectname/Key.p12". I have no idea what i am doing wrong if somebody could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the p12 `File` object like this:

```
File p12 = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/Key.p12").toURI());
```

Comment: No this also doesn't work i am getting a NullPointerException. It says An error occured while executing doInBackground(). Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException.

If i understand correct this will look for the file in the project home directory right? or will it try to look on it in the device?

Comment: This looks for the file in the root of your classpath. Isn't there where you have the p12 file?

Comment: Yeah exactly i was just making sure. I have placed it in the project's directory. Like Project name > Key.p12

Comment: The project's classpath root is in the src dir. Try putting it there.

Comment: I have just tried that too. Project name > app > src > Key.p12. While leaving the code the same but i a still recieving the same error